# Css sprites wrong position

Tags: html, css

I've recently encountered some problems with CSS Sprites.
I want them to switch pictures every function call, function itself is OK since it only removes and adds css class.

I have following CSS:

```
#slider_arrow {
    padding-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

.red_arrow_sprite {
    background: url(/Images/onex/arrows.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 12px;
}

.yellow_arrow_sprite {
    width: 25px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(/Images/onex/arrows.png) -26px 0 no-repeat;
}

.black_arrow_sprite {
    width: 25px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(/Images/onex/arrows.png) -51px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Slider_arrow is:

```
<span id="slider_arrow" class="red_arrow_sprite"></span>
```

the element in which I change class.

And the problem is that my Sprite file has 75px width and 25px height.
(3x 25px/25px)
With the CSS I Presented I get the result where I see all 3 pictures at the time with red_arrow_sprite class, 2 pictures with yellow_arrow_class and 1 picture which is desired with black_arrow_class.

What have I done wrong with CSS?
Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/9b57pb50/

Comment: your img and javascript are missing in the jsfiddle

Comment: You don't need to define width and height in each class http://jsfiddle.net/9b57pb50/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9b57pb50/1/)

I've removed `padding` and add some `display` properties.

Comment: OK :) I've used sample picture but it should works with yours.